# create account with different account in android application

Tags: php, android, localhost

My application now has 2 login , user can login with the application account or facebook, now i would like to ask, when i login with facebook, the username,email and password of facebook account can stored in same table with my application account registration? I am using localhost and php for database and i use android studio to develop app, because now my task is if user login with facebook in my application, when he want create new account, he cannot use same email address with facebook he use to login just now. Hope someone understand my question. Below is my login and register application account code:

Login:

```
<?php 

require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';

$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $db = new DbOperations(); 

    if($db->userLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        $user = $db->getUserByUsername($_POST['username']);
        $response['error'] = false; 
        $response['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];
        $response['email'] = $user['email'];
        $response['username'] = $user['username'];


    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Invalid username or password";          
    }

}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
}
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

register:

```
<?php 

require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';

$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
if(
    isset($_POST['username']) and
        isset($_POST['email']) and
            isset($_POST['password']))
    {
    //operate the data further 

    $db = new DbOperations(); 

    $result = $db->createUser(   $_POST['username'],
                                $_POST['password'],
                                $_POST['email']
                            );
    if($result == 1){
        $response['error'] = false; 
        $response['message'] = "User registered successfully";
    }elseif($result == 2){
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Some error occurred please try again";          
    }elseif($result == 0){
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "It seems you are already registered, please choose a different email and username";                     
    }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
}
}else{
$response['error'] = true; 
$response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: got other answer?

Answer (score 0):

What I do in such a situation is store emails along with user data in database. Along with that, I also store username(To avoid duplication in username). So if user creates a new account, this separate table/collection is checked if such email id exists. If it exists, just show a message to reset password.